# Spring-boot application-test.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, application.properties

I am trying to unit test the spring-boot application using junit. I have placed the application-test.properties under src/test/resources. I have a ApplicationConfiguration Class which reads the application.properties.

My test class looks like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=ApplicationConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
   public class TestBuilders {
      @Autowired
      private ApplicationConfiguration properties;
```

When I try to read the properties, it is always null.

My ApplicationConfiguration Class looks something like this

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value="file:config.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = 
        true)})
public class ApplicationConfiguration{
    private xxxxx;
    private yyyyy;
```

I tried all possible ways that I found on google.. No luck. Please help!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show this class ApplicationConfiguration

Comment: I just edited my question to add ApplicationConfiguration.. When I run the application it is picking up the properties. problem is only when i run the test cases.

Comment: is the properties object null or xxxxx and yyyyy is null?

Comment: Did you create this project with the spring-boot initialiser?

Comment: @pvpkiran properties object is not null... only the fields are null

Comment: @pandaadb no.. I didnt.. I created a  gradle java project... and configured the build.gradle

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The issue is you don't have `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on your test class.
When you load the application it start from main class(one which has `@SpringBootApplication`) where you might have `@EnableConfigurationProperties` and hence it works when you start the application.
 Whereas when you are running the Test with only `ApplicationConfiguration` class as you have specified here

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=ApplicationConfiguration.class)
```

Spring doesn't know that it has to Enable Configuration Properties and hence the fields are not injecting and hence null. But spring is reading your `application-test.properties` file. This can be confirmed by just injecting the value directly in your test class

```
@Value("${xxxxx}")
private String xxxxx;
```

Here the value is injected. But to inject into a class with `ConfigurationProperties` you need to enable it using `@EnableConfigurationProperties`

Put `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on your test class and everythhing works fine.

Comment: OMG! That works.. Thanks a lot!! I tried everything except this!!

Comment: Thank you for this. It's bugged me for so long!