# How to load @ConfigurationProperties on external class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If a bean class comes from an external library (eg my own commons library), how can I populate that bean using `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Example: from a commons library:

```
package com.my.commons.person;

import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Validated
public class CommonPerson {
    private @NotNull String name;
    private @NotNull String age;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(String age) { this.age = age; }
}
```

Implementation  project:

```
package com.my.api;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("commons.person")
    public CommonPerson person() {
        return new CommonPerson();
    }
}
```

application.properties (also only in the implementation project):

```
commons.person.name=Dummy
commons.person.age=30
```

Result:

> application startup fails due to validation exception.
>   o.s.b.b.PropertiesConfigurationFactory   : Field error in object
>   'commons.person' on field 'name': rejected value [null]...

By the way: if I move the `CommonPerson` directly into the implementation project, the code works as expected. It just only does not work if the class is coming from external...

According to the docs this should work though:
[@ConfigurationProperties on thirdparty classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-3rd-party-configuration)

I'm loading my commons package with maven:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>person-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you setters for these fields ?

Comment: Add getters and setters to your `CommonPerson` class

Comment: @davidxxx DAMN! :D stop being faster! ;)

Comment: @Yannic Klem  heyhey :) It is a library class. He/she cannot do it.

Comment: "(eg my own commons library)" i think he/she can change the class, but just in another project

Comment: @Yannic Klem My bad. I didn't see it.

Comment: Of course I have getter+setter in the `CommonPerson`

Comment: @membersound It should work indeed. I tested and it works. A missing thing that causes the issue is probably not shown in your example. Please give more details and post the whole CommonPerson class, including imports.

Comment: @davidxxx added imports of the common class.

Comment: I though of the imports declared in the  CommonPerson class, as well as the whole class definition.

Comment: All the imports I have in the CommonPerson class are added above. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: No, it is fine now. But all seems ok. The error is probably a terrible side effect caused by something in your code/configuration. I advise you to either isolate the issue to understand the origin or use a debugger to debug step by step Spring processings.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So it turned out probably being some caching issue... :( see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @davidxxx and the others, the code itself is correct.

The problem in my case might have been some caching issue from the IDE. I just took out the commons library in the `pom.xml`, saved it, and read it. That somehow triggered a cleanup inside the IDE that a `mvn clean install` did not (as I ran those maven goals several times before).

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable configuration properties support with... `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation, it may help.

Some examples and explanation of usage:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111941/spring-boot-application-test-properties/48114025#48114025) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880453/what-difference-does-enableconfigurationproperties-make-if-a-bean-is-already-an)