# What difference does @EnableConfigurationProperties make if a bean is already annotated with @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[The Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) says that to use the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation

> You also need to list the properties classes to register in the
> `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation, as shown in the following
> example:

and gives this code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AcmeProperties.class)
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

But in the very next paragraph says:

> Even if the preceding configuration creates a regular bean for
> AcmeProperties, we recommend that `@ConfigurationProperties` only deal
> with the environment and, in particular, does not inject other beans
> from the context. Having said that, the `@EnableConfigurationProperties`
> annotation is also automatically applied to your project so that any
> *existing* bean annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` is configured
> from the `Environment`.

Suggesting that listing a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean under an `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation is not necessary.

So which is it? Experimentally, I've seen that if I annotate a bean with `@ConfigurationProperties` it gets properties injected to it as expected without needing to list it in `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, but if this is the case then why list anything that has a `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation under `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, as is shown in the documentation? Does it make any kind of difference?

Comment: check my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111941/spring-boot-application-test-properties/48114025#48114025 This is one example where you might usage of `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is mandatory

Comment: If I understand correctly, this explains why you need `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on a configuration class, but not why you need to give it a list of classes annotated with `@Configurationproperties`, e.g. `@EnableConfigurationProperties(AcmeProperties.class)` when AcmeProperties is already annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As M. Deinum referred `@EnableConfigurationProperties` Is for enabling support of `@ConfigurationProperties`. If you take a look to the annotation Java Doc you can see:

> Enable support for ConfigurationProperties annotated beans. ConfigurationProperties beans can be registered in the standard way (for example using Bean @Bean methods) or, for convenience, can be specified directly on this annotation. [...]

For example, let's say you have a class whose responsibility is to read and store information from your `application.yml` / `application.properties` that is required to make a connection to different databases. You annotate it with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Then, you typically have a `@Configuration` annotated class that provides a `DataSource` `@Bean` to your application. You can use the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to link it to the `@ConfigurationProperties` class and init your data sources accordingly.

Here is a small example:

**application.yml**

```
data-sources:
  db1:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432}/db1"
    username: test
    password: test
  db2:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432}/db2"
    username: test
    password: test
```

**DataSourcesConfiguration**

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class DataSourcesConfiguration {

    private Map<String, BasicDataSource> dataSources;

    public void setDataSources(Map<String, BasicDataSource> dataSources) {
        this.dataSources = dataSources;
    }

    Map<String, BasicDataSource > getDataSources() {
        return dataSources;
    }
}
```

**DataSourceConnectionConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataSourcesConfiguration.class)
public class DatabaseConnectionConfiguration implements Provider<Connection> {

    private DataSourcesConfiguration dataSourcesConfiguration;

    public DatabaseConnectionConfiguration(DataSourcesConfiguration dataSourcesConfiguration) {
        this.dataSourcesConfiguration = dataSourcesConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // Use dataSourcesConfiguration to create application data source. E.g., a AbstractRoutingDataSource..
    }

}
```

Comment: So what difference does including DataSourcesConfiguration.class on the @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation make, compared to leaving the annotation empty?

Comment: The `DataSourcesConfiguration.class` is not registered as a Spring `@Bean`. Hence, if you remove the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` value, in this case `DataSourcesConfiguration.class`, Spring won't be able to find it. If you check the `@EnableConfigurationProperties::value()` docs, it says that it is just a convenient way for quickly register `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated beans. We could leave the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` empty if the `DataSourcesConfiguration` was annotated with, e.g., `@Component` annotation, which registers it as a Spring Bean. Hope this helps!

Comment: Conveniently, `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` is meta-annotated with `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, so if you do a scan of your `config` package where you keep all the properties classes, it will also *enable* configuration properties overall. I annotated my main `@SpringBootApplication` with `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.my.config")`, and the properties were finally being found as beans and getting autowired due to the scan from this one location.

Comment: @EmanuelMiranda Small clarification. `DataSourcesConfiguration` doesn't register _itself_ as a bean. But eventually it is registered as a bean by the `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.
So one way or another `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class should be registered as a bean.

Answer (score 37):

It took me a while to reach to this post but would like to add here so that others may get benefited.

`@ConfigurationProperties` - Used to bind a class with an externalized property file. Very powerful and must be used to separate out bean classes with configuration entity class.

`@Configuration` - Creates a Spring bean of configuration stereotype.

`@EnableConfigurationProperties` - Creates a binding between a configuration entity class and Spring configuration stereotype so that after injection within a service properties can be retrieved easily.

Answer (score 15):

If we look at the code below:

`@Configuration @EnableConfigurationProperties @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="ar1") 
public class ar1Settings { }`

- **@Configuration** tells Spring to treat this as a configuration class and register it as a Bean
- **@EnableConfigurationProperties** tells Spring to treat this class as a consumer of application.yml/properties values
- **@ConfigurationProperties** tells Spring what section this class represents.

My understanding is that if you don't need to specify the section of the property file, then @ConfigurationProperties can be omitted.

Comment: `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is for enabling support of `@ConfigurationProperties` it should only exists once in your application (i.e on your `@SpringBootApplication` it shouldn't (nor does belong) on other classes).

Comment: So what do the classes given to @EnableCOnfigurationProperties as arguments do?

Comment: @JPerson -- they indicate which `@ConfigurationProperties` Spring should enable, specifically. You'd not supply any classes if you'd like any that Spring can find to be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

`@EnableConfigurationProperties` imports `EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar` which enables support for `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated beans.

`@ConfigurationProperties` is an annotation for externalized configuration, it is to be applied to a bean configuration class or method annotated with `@Bean` eg

```
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-prefix")
   public SomePrefix prefixBean() { 
      return new SomePrefix(); 
}
```

To load the properties and bind them to properties within the method or the class that match the prefix.
ps: `some-prefix` binds to `SomePrefix` because of spring's support for Relaxed binding.

Before springboot 2.2, You could do either of the following:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-prefix")
public class ConfigProperties {
//...some code
}
```

or

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeClassToBeBounded.class)
public class ConfigProperties {
```

along with

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-prefix")
public class SomeClassToBeBounded{
//...some code
}
```

From springboot 2.2

You can do it in a much easier way:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-prefix") 
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan 
public class ConfigProperties { 

//...some code
}
```

With this, the classpath scanner enabled by @SpringBootApplication finds the ConfigProperties class, even though we didn't annotate this class with @Component.