# How to inject Spring properties file into JUnit Tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

The unit test class defined in `src/test/...` starts with:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyProperties.class})
public class ConnectionTest {

    @Autowired
    MyProperties props;
// ...
```

The `MyProperties.class` is defined in `src/main/...`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public final class MyProperties {

    @NotEmpty private String name;
// ...
```

When the `MyProperties` is injected in `src/main/...` then the values which it has are taken from `src/resources/application.properties` file.

But when the `MyProperties` is injected in `src/test/...` as I shown above then the values are null.

Comment: Try adding `@Component` to the `MyProperties` class

Comment: `Parameter 1 of method ... in ... required a single bean, but 2 were found: myProperties defined in ... and myProperties defined in null`

Comment: Try to add @EnableAutoConfigurationProperties above ConnectionTest

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111941/spring-boot-application-test-properties/48114025#48114025 This has the solution